# how to plot a line chart as a table using Pinescript?

Tags: datatables, pine-script, linechart

I need a table of a self-made factor of  my strategy's performance be shown on top right of the chart as a table.

IS it possible to plot a line chart there?

I've just search and find nothing related! I almost know hot to plot a table in Pinescript but I didn't find anything related to plot a chart!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot display any line chart, image, line etc. in a table. You just need to display the information as text.